# Should we request an "invite to chat" alert in The 2nd Monitor from Duga?

Tags: discussion, chat, chatbot

> [*could we have Duga let us know here in chat when someone invites a user to chat?*](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22576603#22576603)

I think it would be a good idea, but this affects [The 2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) and Code Review as a community, so I think it should be discussed on Meta before we formally request this change to Duga from its master, [Simon André Forsberg](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/31562/simon-andr%C3%A9-forsberg)

Please let us know how you feel about requesting this addition to Duga.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do we need it? No.

Would it be useful? Perhaps.

Is this something we can change as a community? Well, not really, Duga is not the community's code, so we can make requests, and talk about it, and deny access for things we don't like.... but that's about it.

If you are not talking about Duga, but something else, then propose a new bot, and run it through its tests in a separate room. Then we can talk.